# Triggering an event when abandoning form on an Android application

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to trigger event when a user abandons a form on an android application using google tags manager? or is there a better way

Comment: What does abandon mean in that context? What does the google tag manager have to do with anything here? How do you present the form? Why can't you simply check what the user actively does, e.g. pressing the "Cancel" button?

Comment: @luk2302 If a user on a the adding a post screen for example, and then the user left without submitting a post how can I track it and trigger an event?

Comment: If the browser is e.g. force closed or the phone explodes etc. then no, you cannot trigger anything because your code will no longer be running. What are you trying to achieve and why? You can e.g. use `onbeforeunload` but you won't have any guarantee that it will actually be invoked.